# Programmatically Customizing UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to programmatically create a custom UITableViewCell and implement it into a UITableViewController, but do not know how to. I searched the web and API, and couldn't find a solution to this. There are plenty of "storyboard"esk answers to this, but that is not what I am looking for. So, does anyone know how to do this, and on top of this, customize a UITableViewCell as if it were a UIView (in Objective-C)?

Update: Being more advanced now, than I was, I realize that this was a very bad question. Please ignore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this http://jslim.net/blog/2013/03/22/ios-create-uitableview-with-custom-cell-programmatically/

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me!